# Positions of spines in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot:
[image]

but I would like the ticks to be at the zero axes (as in a normal graph...). 
I have seen [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html) and also [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_axisline_style.html) but am having issues:

if i try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(t):
    A = 2409.505
    rho = 0.3260
    C = 0.00
    if C == 0.0:
        return (A*np.exp(-t/rho))
    else:
        return (A*np.exp(-t/rho)) - (C/r**6)

t1 = np.arange(0, 15, 0.01)
plt.xlim(-1, 16)
plt.ylim(-500, 2500)
plt.spines['left'].setposition('0')
plt.spines['bottom'].setposition('0')
plt.plot(t1, f(t1), 'b', linewidth = '1.5')
plt.tick_params(top = 'off', right = 'off')
plt.grid(linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.05)
plt.show()
```

i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Downloads\pyplot_simple.py", line 16, in <module>
    plt.spines['left'].setposition('0')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spines'
```

and if i try:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(t):
    A = 2409.505
    rho = 0.3260
    C = 0.00
    if C == 0.0:
        return (A*np.exp(-t/rho))
    else:
        return (A*np.exp(-t/rho)) - (C/r**6)

t1 = np.arange(0, 15, 0.01)
plt.xlim(-1, 16)
plt.ylim(-500, 2500)
plt.axis['xzero'].set_axisline_style('-')
plt.axis['xzero'].set_visible(True)
plt.spines['bottom'].setposition('0')
plt.plot(t1, f(t1), 'b', linewidth = '1.5')
plt.tick_params(top = 'off', right = 'off')
plt.grid(linestyle = '--', linewidth = 0.05)
plt.show()
```

i get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rebecca\Downloads\pyplot_simple.py", line 16, in <module>
    plt.axis['xzero'].set_axisline_style('-')
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

I am really confused and I have no doubt I am, once again, missing something really obvious, so any help would be very gratefully received
Cheers

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this:

```
plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_position(('data',0))
```

Comment: or `plt.gca().spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')`